# need to change wocommerce email subject. and want to show product short description

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

1
I am trying change woocommerce email subject change with woocommerce product short description.

this is my code:

```
$this->subject          = __( 'Bid item on {site_title}', 'wc_simple_auctions');
```

i want to show woocommerce product short description on that subject

want to show there this code:

```
printf( __( " %s", 'wc_simple_auctions' ), $product_data->get_short_description()  );
```

Comment: Update your question since you dont ask about woocommerce default emails.

Answer (score 1):

Add following in functions.php and try

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'change_processing_email_subject', 10, 2 );
  
function change_processing_email_subject( $subject, $order ) {
   $subject = $product->get_short_description();
   return $subject;
}
```

Refer: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-email-subject-lines/

Comment: thanks for replay. but i want to change other thing like when customer bid on a auction . i am using woocommerce simple auction . what filter should i use instant of woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order

Comment: @mdsobuz you have documentation here - https://wpgenie.org/woocommerce-simple-auctions/documentation/#faq . Since its premium plugin i would suggest to contact your dev for best advice

Comment: @Martin Mirchev
thanks for replay . I got the plugin from ibid wordpress theme . so i am unable to get support. i try many way and noting works. if you help me to how can i put printf( __( " %s", 'wc_simple_auctions' ), $product_data->get_short_description()  ); on the subject  $this->subject          = __( 'Bid item on {site_title}', 'wc_simple_auctions'); then it will be very kind to me. Today is the last day for delivery order and i am new sp right time delivery is very important